# Python - Dice Game not stopping when hit designated score

Tags: python-3.x, dice

Beginner programmer here! For one of my classes I have to create a dice game that stops when either the player or computer reaches a score of five, however, when one person does reach the desired score, it keeps prompting the player to roll instead of printing the winString or loseString.

EDIT: Sorry for the formatting, this is my first post here and not sure how to fix it. But thanks to your comments I got it to work!

```
import random
from random import randint
import time

playerName = input("Please enter your name ") 

def diceRoll(num_sides=6):
    """Returns number between 1 and 6 (inclusive)"""
    return random.randint(1,num_sides)

def playGameOfDice(playerName):
    print("Hello,",playerName,". Welcome to game of dice! First to five points wins!")
    playerScore = 0
    computerScore = 0
    while playerScore <= 5 or computerScore <= 5: 
        print("The current score is: ",playerName, playerScore, " , computer ",computerScore)
        input("Please press 'Enter' to roll.")
        playerRoll = diceRoll()
        print("Your randomly selected number is.......... "+str(playerRoll)+".") 
        time.sleep(2)
        computerRoll = diceRoll()
        print("Computer's randomly selected number is.......... "+str(computerRoll)+".")
        time.sleep(2)
        for round in range(1):
            if playerRoll > computerRoll:
                print("You Win!")
                playerScore += 1
            elif playerRoll == computerRoll:
                print("Tie Game!")
                computerScore += 1
            else:
                print("You Lose :(")
                computerScore += 1
    if playerScore > computerScore == playerWins:
        return True
    else:
        return False




playerWins = playGameOfDice(playerName)

if playerWins == True:
    winnerString = "*  " + playerName + " Wins!  *"
else:
   winnerString = "*  Good luck next time! Thanks for playing!  *"
```

Comment: Can you please post your code in a more readable format? Right now it's really difficult to follow because it is unformatted.

Comment: It's impossible to read your code like this but I can tell the while loop should be `while playerScore < 5 and computerScore < 5` so it will break when either variable reaches 5.

Comment: It's difficult to read so I can find a proper answer once it is formatted but you could look in to global variables??? Might solve your problem. They're easy.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. There's too much code here for what seems like a relatively simple problem. For example, is `time.sleep` really needed? Is the player's name important?

Answer (score 0):

The line `while playerScore <= 5 or computerScore <= 5:` should use `and` instead, since you want it to break when *either one is false*, so if either of the scores are `>6`, it would break with `and`. Other than that it seems fine?